# MSMQ with asp.net and wcf

Tags: asp.net, wcf, msmq

Currently i'm developing an apllication that sends sms via the asp.net. I'm using msmq for the queuing incase of multiple sending of sms. The wcf will then check for new queue and using teh queue to send out a sms. I've a few question.

1. How do i create a  new queue for the msmq  via asp.net
2. how do i schedule something in wcf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 . How do i create a new queue for the msmq via asp.net

In order to create queues on the fly, you can use `System.Messaging` in .NET - see e.g. this [article on how to do it](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/37330-MSMS-Setup-sample-Code-Try.aspx).

> 2 . how do i schedule something in wcf ?

Why do you need to schedule something in WCF? What are you trying to do, trying to achieve here??

WCF is a service-oriented framework - it's about messages and stuff like that - not scheduling.

Comment: Hi, thx for your input. yup scheduling is not needed. Is the wcf able to have a listener to listen for sms recieved via a usb port? and also a listener to listen for new queeue being added?

Comment: @user492182: no, WCF can listen on a lot of ports - but not on USB, I'm afraid. If you cannot route your SMS into e.g. TCP/IP or something, you'll have to create your own listener on that USB port, I'm afraid...

Comment: oh, so i'll have to create another application for it? :(

Comment: I would try and find out if you can somehow receive that SMS into a SOAP message or something. If that's not possible, and it's delivered to the USB port - yes, some other piece of software will be needed to catch that message coming in; WCF doesn't support anything of that nature